# Programmatic Access to Facebook's "See Friendship" History

Tags: php, facebook

Facebook's "See Friendship" option diplays a complete history of two users' posts on each other's walls. I believe this feature was formerly referred to as "wall-to-wall". Is there  a way to programmatically (via PHP) generate this feed? I could build an array of [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)s by searching the `from` and `to` attributes, but that sounds kind of clunky. Does anyone know of a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no API for this; to rebuild it manually you'd need to access the data of the two users in question, and compare interactions between them to build the list of things they have in common / posts they made on each other's timelines, etc